# Calculating the Integral of a non conservative vector field

Tags: integration, vector-fields

[image]

I have no clue how to do part C because a) is non conservative

What I got for b)
$f(x,y)=\dfrac{x^3}{3}+2yx+\dfrac{y^3}{3}+K$ (I don't know the symbol for the thing so I used f(x,y) instead. How do I do part c?

So what I think I must do:
Change it to polar coordinates with $d\theta$ and $dr$, multiply by the Jacobian matrix determent? I don't know anything about the limits etc. ,but I'm asuming it would be $2\pi$ to $0$. the radius can be found by completing the square and finding radius. Am I correct?

Comment: Can you give the title of the textbook ?

Comment: It a HW assignment, we have no textbook

Comment: See [HW problem 5](http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21a_summer_04/assigned/16.pdf).

Comment: What about my thinking, am I correct? The problem you sent me uses some notations that I don't understand, i'm not too sure about it.

Comment: The point is I don't know what they gave you as a definition of $$\int_C\, \underline F \cdot d\underline r$$

Comment: Neither do I :(